# Oauth and Spring Security

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a server-side application which has two parts. The first part is the REST Apis and the other part is a webpage dashboard which is used for the administration of the whole server-side application.

Now I have used Oauth with spring security for securing REST apis and form-based authentication with Spring security for securing the webpage dashboard. 
But using form-based authentication creates a conflict with the oauth configuration.

Is there any way to use both Oauth and form-based authentication together in Spring security?

This is the securityConfiguration file. I tried adding two configurations but that did not work so i have tried this configuration having two security tags. here the form login configuration works fine but the other configuration that is for oauth does not work.I am able to get the access token but oauth does not work and when trying to access the REST Apis i get redirected to the dashboard login page.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

@Autowired
UserDetailsService webUserDetailsService;



BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public SecurityConfiguration(){
    LOG.debug("OAuthSecurityConfiguration initialized");

    passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    LOG.debug(passwordEncoder);
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {


    auth
        .userDetailsService(webUserDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    LOG.debug("user and password details");
    LOG.debug( auth
        .userDetailsService(webUserDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder));
}

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {

    LOG.debug("authenticationManagerBean");

    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}



@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"**"})
@Order(1)                                                        
public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        LOG.debug(resources);
        resources.resourceId("admin");
        resources.resourceId("admin");
        LOG.debug("configureresource:"+resources.resourceId("admin"));
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("..")                   
            .authorizeRequests()               
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN");
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}

@Configuration  
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"**"})
@Order(2)
public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/login"
                    ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login/new")
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/**", true)
            .failureUrl("/login/fail")
                .permitAll()
           .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login/new")                                  
            .permitAll();
    ;
    }
```

}

Comment: See : http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/

Answer (score 0):

This is well covered by the sparklr sample provided [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/samples/oauth2/sparklr), see OAuth2ServerConfig class.

In your Resource Server configuration class (the one that extends `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`) :

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('some_oauth_scope') or (!#oauth2.isOAuth() and hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN'))")
            // Enable form login 
            .and().formLogin();
    }
}
```

Here your resources under `/api/**` will be accessible both for OAuth 2.0 clients authorized for "some_oauth_scope", or "directly" authenticated users with a role "ADMIN".